# Margin between SimpleDialog Children

Tags: flutter

I have created a `SimpleDialog` in Flutter which shows all the list of country codes. Now I want some margin among all these items. Right now, these are tightly packed to each other.

This is how it looks:
[image: screenshot]]

**Code**

```js
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      title: Text('Select Country'),
      children: countries,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10), );
  });
```

```js
var countries = [
  Text("Afghanistan 93"),
  Text("Albania 355"),
  Text("Algeria 213"),
  Text("American Samoa  1-684"),
  Text("Andorra 376"),
  Text("Angola  244"),
  Text("Anguilla    1-264"),
  Text("Antarctica  672"),
  Text("Antigua and Barbuda 1-268"),
  Text("Argentina   54"),
  Text("Armenia 374"),
  Text("Aruba   297"),
  Text("Australia   61"),
  Text("Austria 43"),
  Text("Azerbaijan  994"),
  Text("Bahamas 1-242"),
  Text("Bahrain 973"),
  Text("Bangladesh  880"),
  Text("Barbados    1-246"),
  Text("Belarus 375"),
  Text("Belgium 32"),
  Text("Belize  501"),
  Text("Benin   229"),
  Text("Bermuda 1-441"),
  Text("Bhutan  975"),
  Text("Bolivia 591"),
  Text("Bosnia and Herzegovina  387"),
  Text("Botswana    267"),
  Text("Brazil  55"),
  Text("British Indian Ocean Territory  246"),
  Text("British Virgin Islands  1-284"),
  Text("Brunei  673"),
  Text("Bulgaria    359"),
  Text("Burkina Faso    226"),
  Text("Burundi 257"),
  Text("Cambodia    855"),
  Text("Cameroon    237"),
  Text("Canada  1"),
  Text("Cape Verde  238"),
  Text("Cayman Islands  1-345"),
  Text("Central African Republic    236"),
  Text("Chad    235"),
  Text("Chile   56"),
  Text("China   86"),
  Text("Christmas Island    61"),
  Text("Cocos Islands   61"),
  Text("Colombia    57"),
  Text("Comoros 269"),
  Text("Cook Islands    682"),
  Text("Costa Rica  506"),
  Text("Croatia 385"),
  Text("Cuba    53"),
  Text("Curacao 599"),
  Text("Cyprus  357"),
  Text("Czech Republic  420"),
  Text("Democratic Republic of the Congo    243"),
  Text("Denmark 45"),
  Text("Djibouti    253"),
  Text("Dominica    1-767"),
  Text("Dominican Republic  1-809, 1-829, 1-849"),
  Text("East Timor  670"),
  Text("Ecuador 593"),
  Text("Egypt   20"),
  Text("El Salvador 503"),
  Text("Equatorial Guinea   240"),
  Text("Eritrea 291"),
  Text("Estonia 372"),
  Text("Ethiopia    251"),
  Text("Falkland Islands    500"),
  Text("Faroe Islands   298"),
  Text("Fiji    679"),
  Text("Finland 358"),
  Text("France  33"),
  Text("French Polynesia    689"),
  Text("Gabon   241"),
  Text("Gambia  220"),
  Text("Georgia 995"),
  Text("Germany 49"),
  Text("Ghana   233"),
  Text("Gibraltar   350"),
  Text("Greece  30"),
  Text("Greenland   299"),
  Text("Grenada 1-473"),
  Text("Guam    1-671"),
  Text("Guatemala   502"),
  Text("Guernsey    44-1481"),
  Text("Guinea  224"),
  Text("Guinea-Bissau   245"),
  Text("Guyana  592"),
  Text("Haiti   509"),
  Text("Honduras    504"),
  Text("Hong Kong   852"),
  Text("Hungary 36"),
  Text("Iceland 354"),
  Text("India   91"),
  Text("Indonesia   62"),
  Text("Iran    98"),
  Text("Iraq    964"),
  Text("Ireland 353"),
  Text("Isle of Man 44-1624"),
  Text("Israel  972"),
  Text("Italy   39"),
  Text("Ivory Coast 225"),
  Text("Jamaica 1-876"),
  Text("Japan   81"),
  Text("Jersey  44-1534"),
  Text("Jordan  962"),
  Text("Kazakhstan  7"),
  Text("Kenya   254"),
  Text("Kiribati    686"),
  Text("Kosovo  383"),
  Text("Kuwait  965"),
  Text("Kyrgyzstan  996"),
  Text("Laos    856"),
  Text("Latvia  371"),
  Text("Lebanon 961"),
  Text("Lesotho 266"),
  Text("Liberia 231"),
  Text("Libya   218"),
  Text("Liechtenstein   423"),
  Text("Lithuania   370"),
  Text("Luxembourg  352"),
  Text("Macau   853"),
  Text("Macedonia   389"),
  Text("Madagascar  261"),
  Text("Malawi  265"),
  Text("Malaysia    60"),
  Text("Maldives    960"),
  Text("Mali    223"),
  Text("Malta   356"),
  Text("Marshall Islands    692"),
  Text("Mauritania  222"),
  Text("Mauritius   230"),
  Text("Mayotte 262"),
  Text("Mexico  52"),
  Text("Micronesia  691"),
  Text("Moldova 373"),
  Text("Monaco  377"),
  Text("Mongolia    976"),
  Text("Montenegro  382"),
  Text("Montserrat  1-664"),
  Text("Morocco 212"),
  Text("Mozambique  258"),
  Text("Myanmar 95"),
  Text("Namibia 264"),
  Text("Nauru   674"),
  Text("Nepal   977"),
  Text("Netherlands 31"),
  Text("Netherlands Antilles    599"),
  Text("New Caledonia   687"),
  Text("New Zealand 64"),
  Text("Nicaragua   505"),
  Text("Niger   227"),
  Text("Nigeria 234"),
  Text("Niue    683"),
  Text("North Korea 850"),
  Text("Northern Mariana Islands    1-670"),
  Text("Norway  47"),
  Text("Oman    968"),
  Text("Pakistan    92"),
  Text("Palau   680"),
  Text("Palestine   970"),
  Text("Panama  507"),
  Text("Papua New Guinea    675"),
  Text("Paraguay    595"),
  Text("Peru    51"),
  Text("Philippines 63"),
  Text("Pitcairn    64"),
  Text("Poland  48"),
  Text("Portugal    351"),
  Text("Puerto Rico 1-787, 1-939"),
  Text("Qatar   974"),
  Text("Republic of the Congo   242"),
  Text("Reunion 262"),
  Text("Romania 40"),
  Text("Russia  7"),
  Text("Rwanda  250"),
  Text("Saint Barthelemy    590"),
  Text("Saint Helena    290"),
  Text("Saint Kitts and Nevis   1-869"),
  Text("Saint Lucia 1-758"),
  Text("Saint Martin    590"),
  Text("Saint Pierre and Miquelon   508"),
  Text("Saint Vincent and the Grenadines    1-784"),
  Text("Samoa   685"),
  Text("San Marino  378"),
  Text("Sao Tome and Principe   239"),
  Text("Saudi Arabia    966"),
  Text("Senegal 221"),
  Text("Serbia  381"),
  Text("Seychelles  248"),
  Text("Sierra Leone    232"),
  Text("Singapore   65"),
  Text("Sint Maarten    1-721"),
  Text("Slovakia    421"),
  Text("Slovenia    386"),
  Text("Solomon Islands 677"),
  Text("Somalia 252"),
  Text("South Africa    27"),
  Text("South Korea 82"),
  Text("South Sudan 211"),
  Text("Spain   34"),
  Text("Sri Lanka   94"),
  Text("Sudan   249"),
  Text("Suriname    597"),
  Text("Svalbard and Jan Mayen  47"),
  Text("Swaziland   268"),
  Text("Sweden  46"),
  Text("Switzerland 41"),
  Text("Syria   963"),
  Text("Taiwan  886"),
  Text("Tajikistan  992"),
  Text("Tanzania    255"),
  Text("Thailand    66"),
  Text("Togo    228"),
  Text("Tokelau 690"),
  Text("Tonga   676"),
  Text("Trinidad and Tobago 1-868"),
  Text("Tunisia 216"),
  Text("Turkey  90"),
  Text("Turkmenistan    993"),
  Text("Turks and Caicos Islands    1-649"),
  Text("Tuvalu  688"),
  Text("U.S. Virgin Islands 1-340"),
  Text("Uganda  256"),
  Text("Ukraine 380"),
  Text("United Arab Emirates    971"),
  Text("United Kingdom  44"),
  Text("United States   1"),
  Text("Uruguay 598"),
  Text("Uzbekistan  998"),
  Text("Vanuatu 678"),
  Text("Vatican 379"),
  Text("Venezuela   58"),
  Text("Vietnam 84"),
  Text("Wallis and Futuna   681"),
  Text("Western Sahara  212"),
  Text("Yemen   967"),
  Text("Zambia  260"),
  Text("Zimbabwe    263")
];
```

Comment: If you can share your code, that would be more helpful for us to help you.

Comment: Looking at your UI seems, you need to use the Padding widget in your list item UI and need to add the required padding as per your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create widget and pass country name on it

```
Widget getCountryName(String name){
  return
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child:Text(name),
    );
}

var countries = [
  getCountryName("Afghanistan 93"),
  getCountryName("Albania 355"),
]
```

Comment: I have 200+ country values in my list. Am in going to call this function that many times?

Comment: Yes Like Text you have called multiple time.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your country code widget with Padding widget and add some padding to it, or with Container widget and add some padding/margin to it, like this:

```
Container(
  // padding instead of margin also works fine
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: Text('county code') // your current widget that needs some margin
),
```